# Combining functions that return futures

Tags: c++, future

Suppose I have two functions that return futures:

```
std::future<T> foo(int);

std::future<U> bar(T const &);
```

I want to combine the two functions to a function that takes an `int` as parameter and returns a `std::future<U>`. How should I write this function? Is it possible to generalize function composition for functions that return futures?

```
std::future<U> foobar1(int x)
{
  auto foo_x = foo(x);
  return bar(foo_x.get());
}
```

This function will block until the future returned by `foo` is finished, right? This is clearly not what I want.

```
std::future<U> foobar2(int x)
{
  return std::async([=]()
  {
    auto foo_x = foo(x);
    return bar(foo_x.get()).get();
  });
}
```

It feels silly to call `get()` on the future returned by `bar` just to have it turned into a new future by `std::async`

```
std::future<U> foobar3(int x)
{
  return foo(x).then([](std::future<T> f)
  {
    return bar(f.get()).get();
  };
}
```

Here, again I have to call `get()` on the future returned by `bar` otherwise I'd have a `future<future<U>>`. Is this the correct approach?

Answer (score 9):

What you want is a monad. `std::future` is almost but not quite a monad but lacks the ability to properly compose functions by lifting them as you have noticed. For a detailed discussion on this please see [this blog post](http://bartoszmilewski.com/2014/02/26/c17-i-see-a-monad-in-your-future/).

The summary is that for C++17 an additional method has been proposed for `std::future`: either `next` or `then` which would take a function to be applied to the future's value once it is available. This would be roughly equivalent to `bind` in Haskell for example (note: not `std::bind`).

Let's take the two functions:

```
T foo(int);
U bar(T const &);
```

Here we have a mapping `int -> T -> U`, what you want is to lift this mapping to `int -> std::future<T> -> std::future<U>`. What this might look like would be:

```
int x = 2;
std::async([=](){return foo(x);}).then(bar);
```

Where `then` is a function that automatically maps `T -> U` to `std::future<T> -> std::future<U>`.

**Disclaimer:** I am not a Haskell programmer and realise I have probably got everything mixed up. I gladly welcome corrections.